# Java pass a class to check instance of

Tags: java

I want to pass a class to a function. In that function, new instance of other classes are created.

Then, I want to be able to find which object there is an instance of the class I passed:

```
public void doSomething(Class cls) {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();

    if (obj instanceof cls) {
        // Do amazing things here
    }
}

class Person {
    // This exists
}

doSomething(Person.class);
```

The code above doesn't work. I hope I'm clear enough what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Class. It's in there.

Comment: Also: don't use a raw type, use `Class<?>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-.

```
if (cls.isInstance(obj)){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if an object is an instance of a class type, you need to call `isInstance`:

```
if (cls.isInstance(obj)){

}
```

Or you can do `isAssignableFrom`:

```
if (clas.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {

}
```

Comment: `obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(cls)` will tell you if `cls` is a subclass of `obj`'s type.